# Compute $\int_{\{|z|=4\}}\frac{z^2+2}{(z-3)^2}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I want to compute the value of the complex line integral
$$\int_{\{|z|=4\}}\frac{z^2+2}{(z-3)^2}dz$$
I don't think I can apply Cauchy's integral theorem nor Cauchy's integral formula here. So far, I have tried parametrizing $\{|z|=4\}$ as $\gamma(\theta)=4e^{i\theta}$ and expanding the function I am integrating, however I don't think this is a good way to proceed. Can someone help me?

Comment: [what is $\int_{|z|=3}\frac{1}{(z-2)^n(z-4)^m}dz$ for $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615890/what-is-int-z-3-frac1z-2nz-4mdz-for-m-n-in-mathbbn) - how to handle non-simple poles!

Comment: How about the residue theorem?

Comment: Do you knoe Cauchy's Integral formula for derivatives or the Residue Theorem?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can use Cauchy's integral formula for derivatives, with the holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}, f(z)=z^2+2$.

Then, for any $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z_0|<4$, we get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=4}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}dz=f'(z_0)=2z_0.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Answer (score 1):

Use $\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}Ind_{\gamma}(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz$.
(Ind = Winding number)

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.